# How to draw equally spaced dots on a circle in manim?

Tags: python, manim

In manimce,

How to draw equally spaced dots on a circle as shown below?

[image]

I can calculate each point's coordinates by hand and input them, but is there an easy build in way to input dots in manim?

---

> [Image credits](https://www2.edc.org/makingmath/mathsettings/connect/connect.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explains that the `Circle` object has a method `point_at_angle`. [PointAtAngle Example](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.geometry.Circle.html#pointatangleexample)

The `point_at_angle` method takes a single argument which is the angle of the point along the circle in radians.

Here is some code to draw a green circle and 16 red dots on its circumference:

```
from manim import *

class PointsOnCircle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle(radius=3.0, color=GREEN)
        # Number of points required
        num_points = 16
        # Calculate each angle
        angles = [n * (360 / num_points) for n in range(num_points)]
        # Points on circumference of circle
        points = [circle.point_at_angle(n*DEGREES) for n in angles]
        # Create circles at each point
        circles = [Circle(radius=0.05, color=RED, fill_opacity=1).move_to(p) for p in points]
        # Add the circle to the scene
        self.add(circle)
        # Add each of the points to the scene
        for c in circles:
            self.add(c)
```

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed the "reference manual"